# Mysql queries for date difference in days

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, query-optimization

Need help here, having an mysql table called **APPROVAL**, there having an `id,dateandtime` and `level, i` need a query that selects the `id` alone with the following condition.

Taking date alone from database and comparing it with current system date, if the days exceeds above **30** and below **60** and also `level = 5`.

How can I write a query for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sry sir i dont have idea how to write this query, iam a bit newbie here.

Comment: I won't downvote you, but I suggest you to edit your question because it hardly clear.. ( and usually people say hello and thanks when they are in need )

Comment: So ( as it is still not that clear ...) you want to retrieve the id of the records that match level = 5 and if the date difference is between 30 and 60, don't you?

Comment: Yes sir you are correct :)

Comment: Ok below the query, test it on your script and revert ;) have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so use this query to retrieve all the IDs that match level 5 and date diff between 30 and 60 compared to the current date.

```
SELECT id
FROM APPROVAL
WHERE level = 5 && DATEDIFF(NOW(), dateandtime) BETWEEN 30 AND 60
```

I'd suggest you to order them dy date DESC too.

Hope that helps

Comment: The search on DateTime you've proposed can't exploit an index.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has good date arithmetic.  For example, the expression

```
 CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

gives a datetime value denoting midnight 30 days hence.  Similarly

```
CURDATE()  + INTERVAL 61 DAY
```

yields midnight on the 61st day.

So a query of the form

```
   SELECT ID
     FROM APPROVAL
    WHERE Level = 5
      AND `DateTime` >=  CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY
      AND `DateTime` <   CURDATE() + INTERVAL 61 DAY
```

will yield what you want. Notice the use of `>=` for the beginning of the range of days, and the use of `<` and an extra day for the end of the range. We do that because we want all items from the 60th day, and none from the 61st day.

A compound index on `(Level, DateTime)` will make this query very efficient to satisfy.

Notice that an expression like

```
    DATE(`DateTime`) <=   CURDATE() + INTERVAL 60 DAY  /* slow! */
```

will also yield correct results, but the presence of the the `DATE()` function call on the column to be searched makes it *[unsargeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)*. That is, it makes MySQL unable to use an index to satisfy the search.

Comment: Thank u sir for u quick response, how can i write this query in the form of PHP code igniter framework.

Comment: @Crysis How to put it into codeigniter is a different question. You probably should do a bit of research and if you can'f figure it out, ask that question separately. At any rate I'm not a codeIgniter user so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, I understood your problem correctly.

```
select `ID`
from APPROVAL
where `Level` = 5
    and ( DATE(`DateTime`) > curdate() + interval 30 day 
        and DATE(`DateTime`) < curdate() + interval 60 day )
order by `ID` asc;
```

Where [DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) gets the date from a datetime and [CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) is the current system date. With `interval` you can manipulate a date expression whitout having to worry about its limits.

Comment: The search on DateTime you've proposed can't exploit an index.

Comment: @OllieJones Thanks for the input. Seeing your answer it makes sense. :)